# Getting "Method not found" exception when calling a method from API on azure server

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-webjobs

I am getting an exception on "Method not found" when calling a method from API hosted on azure server. But the call gives the desired results when hosted on some other server or on my localhost.
Do i need to do any settings in azure portal for this?
Because all other methods are working fine but the new once giving problem.

Comment: Are you sure the version with the new method(s) is correctly deployed to Azure and that you are working against the correct deployment?

Comment: Yes,Every other change is working just this method is giving the error.

Comment: Is the route added, either through an attribute or a general route? Are you using the right verb? Maybe you could add some code of the method that isn't being found.

Answer (score 0):

> Do i need to do any settings in azure portal for this?

I just tested following method on Azure Web App. All of them worked fine. We don't need to add additional setting in azure portal.

```
GET,POST,Head,Options,Patch,Put,Delete
```

You could create a simple code to test the dedicated method. Code below is for your reference.

```
public string Patch()
{
    return "Patch OK";
}


public string Delete()
{
    return "delete OK";
}
```

> Getting “Method not found” exception when calling a method from API on azure server

For this exception, I suggest you use a HTTP traffic detection tool(For example Fiddler) to check the request message(include HTTP method/URL/Request body etc.) which was sent to the API server. Please make sure the request message is the right message which you want to send.

You also need to check whether you have send the enough information to the API. For example, a PUT API is defined as following.

```
public string Put(int id)
{
    return "put method response " + id.ToString();
}
```

If we invoke the API without provide the query string id in the URL. A method is not found exception will be thrown.

```
PUT /api/controllername?id=1
```

Comment: Any updates? If you have further questions, please feel free to let me know.